# yii2 xSendFile настройка nginx

Tags: yii2, nginx

Здравствуйте. Столкнулся с проблемо в yii2, не могу правильно настроить nginx для отдачи файлов через xSendFile. Ссылка в оф. документации не рабочая. Может есть какая-то статья, или пример конфигурации. Сам разобраться так и не смог.

Answer (score 0):

[https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/495553616dc41b9a5db141931388d9502d19eb13/docs/guide-ru/runtime-responses.md#Отправка-файлов-](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/495553616dc41b9a5db141931388d9502d19eb13/docs/guide-ru/runtime-responses.md#%D0%9E%D1%82%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2-)
https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/495553616dc41b9a5db141931388d9502d19eb13/framework/web/Response.php#L691

Как-то так:

```
class SiteController extends Controller
{
    public function actionIndex()
    {
        return Yii::$app->getResponse()->xSendFile(__DIR__ . '/SiteController.php');
    }
}
```

Comment: Возможно не так объяснил. Синтаксис в самом yii2 я нашел. Мне не понятно как сконфигурировать nginx. Хотя теперь я еще больше запутался: вы в качестве пути к файлу указали путь к файлу контроллера, это просто для примера?

Comment: Это рабочий пример. У меня стоит стандартный nginx без всяких дополнительных настроек. Файл SiteController.php при нормальных настройках nginx невозможно скачать, поэтому в качестве примера выбрал именно его. У меня скачала файл из закрытой директории с оригинальным именем.

Comment: К сожалению у меня данный пример работает не правильно, скачивается файл весом 0. В доках к yii написано что это из-за неверной конфигурации nginx. Но спасибо за ответ.